# Labeling ggplot graph categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am trying to plot a "geom_point" graph using ggplot. The points have a 15 categories (sector), which makes difficult to distinguish between the different categories of sector variable.

I used this code

```
 ggplot(bas_prod, aes(y=Sal_Prom, x=Complejidad,
                 color=sector, shape=sector))+
 geom_point(size=2)+
 geom_boxplot()+
 geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
 scale_shape_manual(values=seq(0,15))
```

to get the graph contained in the following link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI5Hf.jpg

I want to put a label to each aside with each line but don´t know how to do it.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at `geom_text`

Comment: Please provide sample data using `dput(head(mydata,25))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you although I wouldn't recommend you to visualize your data like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species,Petal.Length,col=Species,shape=Species))+
  geom_point()+geom_boxplot()+
  geom_label(aes(label=Species),show.legend = F)
```